# how to launch GANACHE etheruim client like below image?

Tags: ethereum

[image]

I installed ganache-cli by below commend

```
 npm install -g ganache-cli
```

i have Downloaded the file

> ganache-1.1.0-beta.0-x86_64.AppImage

when i click on that image
some process was done after that noting is happiening then i close it
when i click again it again save file like below

ganache-1.1.0-beta.0-x86_64.AppImage.par2

Ref : http://truffleframework.com/docs/ganache/using

my point is :
**how to launch GANACHE  etheruim client  like below image ??**

Answer (score 4):

Download the AppImage from [Download Ganache](http://truffleframework.com/ganache/) and run without installation
If Its not executable then make it. Here is the command :

```
chmod a+x ganache-1.1.0-x86_64.AppImage
```

[image]

Comment: Then run it with:
./ganache-1.1.0-x86_64.AppImage

Answer (score 0):

As written on Git repo "/trufflesuite/ganache-cli" cli is command line tool:
"Ganache CLI, part of the Truffle suite of Ethereum development tools, **is the command line version of Ganache**, your personal blockchain for Ethereum development."

You can download the one with UI from your picture

- on Git repo "trufflesuite/ganache" ("Ganache.appx" is the one)
- on their web page [here](http://truffleframework.com/ganache/)

Comment: You can download it from here too:
https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/releases

Answer (score 0):

Refer below article. And, let me give you the steps.

once you download Ganache from GIT, unzip it and go to that folder. And then two commands.

```
npm install 
npm start
```

that's it.

https://medium.com/@erdoganbavas/how-to-install-ganache-on-windows-10-1c9b6b3361ab